# AttributeError: module 'syft' has no attribute 'FederatedDataLoader'

Tags: python, tensorflow, federated-learning, pysyft

I have just started using `pysyft` to implement federated-learning. While following one of the tutorials, I got stuck on an error:

[image]

Code which I have used:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import logging
import syft as sy

westside = sy.VirtualMachine(name = "westside")
grapevine = sy.VirtualMachine(name = "grapevine")

# Introducing hyperparameters to control the learning process
args = {
    'use_cuda': True,
    'batch_size': 64,
    'test_batch_size': 1000,
    'lr': 0.01,
    'log_interval': 100,
    'epochs': 10
}

# Check to use GPU or not
use_cuda = args['use_cuda'] and torch.cuda.is_available()
device = torch.device('cuda' if use_cuda else 'cpu')

# Create a simple CNN net
class Net(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 1, out_channels = 32, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32,out_channels = 64, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=64*12*12, out_features=128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=10),
        )
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)
        x = x.view(-1, 64*12*12)
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
        return x

# Load the data and transform it into a federated dataset
federated_train_loader = sy.FederatedDataLoader(
    datasets.MNIST('../data', train=True, download=True,
                   transform=transforms.Compose([
                       transforms.ToTensor(),
                       transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                   ]))
    .federate((grapevine, westside)),
    batch_size=args['batch_size'], shuffle=True)
```

The tutorial which I am following uses an old version of `pysyft` so the support for `hooks` has been deprecated. Also, I had to use `syft.VirtualMachine(name="Some-name")` instead of `syft.VirtualWorker(hook, id="Some-name")`. The purpose of `sy.FederatedDataLoader` as given in the tutorial is to load data and hence, transform it to `federated dataset`. This is the link for the [tutorial](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/Federated-Learning-Intro/Federated_Learning_Tutorial.ipynb). Is there any equivalent function instead of `FederatedDataLoader()` to load data in the new version?

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of PySyft you can use it as follow:

westside = sy.Worker(name="westside")

Without the need to downgrade the version.

Answer (score 0):

try to install PySyft version : 0.2.9